# Node.js, socket.io and base64-to-image not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using node.js and socket.io to transfer an image from a server to a client. These are my codes ,

> renderer.js:

```
const imgFile = fs.readFileSync(screenShotPath);
                    const imgFile64 = new Buffer(imgFile).toString('base64');
                    console.log("image data:"+ imgFile64);
                    socket.emit('img', imgFile64);
```

> receiver.js:

```
    var base64ToImage = require('base64-to-image');
socket.on("img", function(info) {
    console.log("inside receiver");
    var base64Str = info;
    var path = 'path to file'; 
    var optionalObj = {'fileName': 'test', 'type':'png'};
    var imageInfo = base64ToImage(base64Str,path,optionalObj);
});
```

I am getting an error stating 'Invalid base64 string'. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: i think you need to  do base64Str.replace(/^data:([A-Za-z-+/]+);base64,/, ''); befor running the base64ToImage

Comment: hey @arunp9294 i converted it with the bas64-image npm but now the image is getting created

Comment: https://github.com/guo-yu/base64-image/blob/master/index.js internally does the same thing.. and only support png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without `base64-to-image`

```
socket.on("img", function(info) {
    console.log("inside receiver");
    var base64Str = info;
    var buff = new Buffer(base64Str ,"base64");
    fs.writeFileSync("test.png", buff)
});
```

**PS:**
On the server side, you don't have to do `new Buffer(imgFile)` because `imgFile` is already `Buffer`

Comment: #Dushyant Bangal how do i specify path, it should be fs.writeFIleSync("C:\users\Desktop\test.png",buff); isnt it?

Comment: here `test.png` is the path. You can specify your whole path there `/home/my/directory/test.png`. In case of windows, `D:\\my\\directory\\test.png`